# Status bar disapear on iOS 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, statusbar, xcode5

Since I upgraded my app to Xcode 5 the status bar disappear when i run the app under iOS 6. The app is in full screen and there is no status bar at all.

Under iOS 7 the app is in full screen but the status bar (transparent background and black informations) is visible above the app.

How to get it back in iOS 6 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you should double check you haven't ticked the "`Hide during application launch`" option under your target's General tab like so:

[image]

Additionally you can add the following key in your `Info.plist`:

[image]

In your application's delegate in `- (BOOL) application: (UIApplication *) application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: (NSDictionary *) launchOptions` add the following statement:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden: NO];
```

I hope this helps solves your issue.